# A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying Ehcache. you should consider increasing the cache timeouts and/or capacity limits

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

```
        18:39:39,368 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-18080-1) HHH020008: Cache[com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.User] Key[com.ust.wmi.lakshya.model.User#24047MAN] Lockable[(null)]
        A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying Ehcache. If this happens regularly you should consider increasing the cache timeouts and/or capacity limits

        In my project I have two configurations for the cache those are  one is Ehcahce and JCS cache, Following are the configurations.

        **JCS configuration**
        jcs.region.oms=DC
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=2000
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName=org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker=true
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds=86400
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds=60
        jcs.region.oms.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun=500
        jcs.region.oms.elementattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes
        jcs.region.oms.elementattributes.IsEternal=false

    Above is the JCS configuration to store my token to Authenticate further with tab.    



        **Ehcache Configuration**
        <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"> 
        <defaultCache
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true"  
              overflowToDisk="false" 
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="allSegments" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="allMembers" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="allStores" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="allBdas" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="allProducts" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="activeOrders" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="agencies" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="mobilemoneys" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
          <cache name="allBDAsForDrop" 
              maxElementsInMemory="1000"  
              eternal="true" 
              overflowToDisk="false"
              memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />   
        </ehcache>
```

The above configuration is to store the Frequently using objects in to my cache.
We have the total 9 basic rapidly using objects so i m saving those in the ehcache after i m retrieving the object when ever user requests.

```
I m getting the following warning message. And my objects are not storing in cache.
        When it loggged in from tab one rest service will call and create the token after I m saving the token in the cache for the further requests.
        Now it is not showing the cache instead it is showing the above message.

        Can anyone please help me any modifications needed to overcome that error.`enter code here`
```

Comment: You do not need to establish a connection for that. To access a table in a different schema of the same database your user just need to be granted object privileges on that table.

Comment: no need to trigger, just need grant

Comment: Hi Ersin, Thank you so much. If possible provide me the Grant object 
Query.